# cache : "drush cr" versus admin toolbar "flush all caches"

Tags: theming, 8, blocks, caching

What the drush cr would do that the flush all caches would not?
Particularely regarding block caching?

I got mad trying to set a custom block twig template for eventually figuring out that nothing was wrong with my code but flush all caches was not enough and drush cr would do the job.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2640110

EDIT: could there be a bias of my local dev settings ?

```
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';

$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

Answer (score 1):

Drush's cache-rebuild command does the following:

- Clears the APC cache
- Bootstraps Drupal
- Calls drupal_rebuild()
- Clears the Drush cache (to maintain consistency with Drupal 7's drush cache-clear command)

Source: https://drupalize.me/tutorial/clear-drupals-cache?p=2512.

In drupal 8 it is recommended to use cache-rebuild instead of cache-clear.
Your dev settings shouldn't matter for this.

in drupal 8 the drush cc all is deprecated and yo should always use drush cr.